# If $\|u\| = 1 \leq \|v\|$ and $w = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$ in a Banach Space. Can we expect that $K \|u-w\| \geq \|u-v\| $, for $K > 0$?

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality

Let E be a Banach Space and $u,v \in E$ s.t. $\|u\| = 1 \leq \|v\|$. Denote $w = \frac{v}{\|v\|}$. In general we can't expect $\|u-w\| \geq \|u-v\|$. Although, can we expect that for $K > 0$, $K \|u-w\| \geq \|u-v\| $ ?

Comment: Is your banach uniformly convex or something like that ?

Comment: not necessarily, but if we add that hypothesis work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Just take $\|u\|=1$, $v=t u$, $t>1$. Then $u=w$ but $u\ne v$.